# Returning Place Description on Google Places API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places

Apologies if this has been answered already. I cannot find it and im very new to the G.Places API for iOS.

Question: How do I get a place's description using the Places API and GMSPlaces Class? Currently, I can already return a place's name, coordinates/address, website, etc

I basically want to return Google's place descriptions ie when I search Nike Store I want to get: "Five-level megastore selling all types of sneakers, including customizable options, plus sportswear. - Google" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as there's no corresponding property for this in iOS API, looks like unfortunately you can't get description of the place.

However, you **may get** sort of description, if use [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults)  which results may contain

> *long_name* is the full text description or name of the address component.

Comment: In this answer _full text description_ relates to the **address_components** field returned.  In this case, _long_name_ might be **San Francisco** where _short_name_ is **SF**.  @nubthenoob is looking for the brief text description that is listed on most Google Places.  I do not believe this is currently available via the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).